# função em VBA para tornar texto em maiúsculo

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções, vba, texto

Boa tarde. Como tornar maiúsculos os trextos de apenas algumas células de um formulário montado em uma planilha excel? Células de campos numéricos e de e-mails não devem sofrer alteração.
Só encontrei fórmulas e funções para células isoladas, colunas ou a planilha inteira, mas preciso para algumas células alternadas em colunas e linhas diversas.

Comment: Coloque uma imagem com o seu formulário para nos ajudar a entender o que vc tem e o que deseja obter. Sua explicação está bem confusa!

Comment: A fórmula `=MAIÚSCULA()` não te resolve o problema?

Comment: Não, porque eu preciso tornar maiúsculo o texto na mesma célula onde é digitado.

Comment: Lhe dei duas respostas mas não recebi feedback. Contribua com a comunidade acompanhando suas perguntas também.

Answer (score 0):

Via VBA, vc pode associar o seguinte código a evento `Change`` no módulo de Sheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B20")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target = UCase(Target)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode forçar o usuário a digitar apenas em letras maiúsculas via Validação de Dados. Selecione o intervalo e clique em Validação de Dados. Em 'Permitir', selecione a opção 'Personalizada' e no campo 'Fórmula' digite a função `=EXATO(A1;MAIÚSCULA(A1))`.

[image: Validação de textos em letras maiúsculas]

(se seu Excel estiver em inglês, basta copiar os textos da imagem)